# What is this spell-checker like feature which is not linked to an addon?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

One of my installs of Visual Studio Code has a feature which I do not know how to remove. When typing a tag, there is an entry with an `abc` icon which looks like a check speller and which I cannot link to neither setting, nor add-on:

[image]

The other entries identify the add-on they come from (and are therefore easy to disable or uninstall):

[image]

Since I could not find it in `Settings`, it is either a better-hidden setting, or a plugin which does not identify itself (another instance of VSCode I have elsewhere does not have it).

**Can you please help to identify it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `abc` entries are the *typed words* in your file.

Since you typed `div` one line above, when you start typing `di`, the autocomplete feature will show up the *previously typed words* that starts with `di`, *snippets* that starts with `di` and *other language features* (depending on extensions you installed).

You can turn off this suggestions if you set `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions"` to `false`:

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```